# ActionScript Error 1151: randomly selected obstacle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, namespaces

I'm relatively new to actionscript, and I'm trying to have a randomly selected obstacle be selected to come flying at my player character.  I keep getting error 1151: a conflict exists with definition obstInstance in namespace internal. I get that same error three times. I think it's because I am repeatedly assigning the same obstacle instance new values (even though it's within a conditional format). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstacleGenerator);
function obstacleGenerator(e:Event):void
{
trace("Obstacle Generator Initiated");
var obstacleSelector:uint=Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
trace("Obstacle Number ", obstacleSelector);

if (obstacleSelector==1){
    var obstInstance:Obj1 = new Obj1();
}
else if (obstacleSelector==2){
    var obstInstance:Obj2 = new Obj2(); //error 1151
}
else if (obstacleSelector==3){
    var obstInstance:Obj3 = new Obj3(); //error 1151
}
else if (obstacleSelector==4){
    var obstInstance:Obj4 = new Obj4(); //error 1151
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to give 4 different objects the same name. Each needs a separate name. You could then create a variable to hold the currentObject and use that as a reference.

Try

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstacleGenerator);

var currentObj:Object;

var obstInstance1:Obj1;
var obstInstance2:Obj2;
var obstInstance3:Obj3;
var obstInstance4:Obj4;

function obstacleGenerator(e:Event):void
{

    var obstacleSelector:uint=Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);


    if (obstacleSelector==1){
        setCurrentObj(obstInstance1 = new Obj1())
    }
    else if (obstacleSelector==2){
        setCurrentObj(obstInstance2  = new Obj2())
    }
    else if (obstacleSelector==3){
        setCurrentObj(obstInstance3  = new Obj3())
    }
    else if (obstacleSelector==4){
        setCurrentObj(obstInstance4 = new Obj4())
    }
}

function setCurrentObj(myObject:Object):void{
     currentObj = myObject;
}
```